# java- call variables using string that contains the variable name

Tags: java

I'm trying to initialize 18 label with some string
my labels are of the form

```
label1 , label2 , label3 , ..... , label18
```

is there a way i use a loop with something like

```
label + i
```

to get each one of my labels and perform some operation on it ?

Comment: Yes, use an array or an ArrayList. That's what they're for. i.e., `SomeType[] labels = new SomeType[18];`

Comment: @Ahmed Fahmy, it's not possible to do whatever you are thinking to do in Java. Instead, use string array, for example, String[ ] labelArray = new String[ ]; for(int i = 0; i < 18 ; i++) { labelArray[ i ] = "test label"; }. And you can again use same for loop to extract the value. Hope it's helps you.

Comment: Thank you , i didn't manage to solve it , i manually assigned all created variables to array indexes and used it to reference the original variables